# Bootstrap 5 - Non-functional toggle button

Tags: bootstrap-5

I have built out a toggle button using Bootstrap 5, but it's not functional.

My nav bar shows all links on larger screens, and the toggle button appears on smaller screens. However, when clicking the toggle, nothing happens. I'm pretty sure I have the proper info in the header and body to use Bootstrap; other aspects of the code work as expected. I also have corresponding target and id. I can't come up with any other issues that may be contributing to the problem. TIA for any help.

````html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8" />
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" 
  rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-
  T3c6CoIi6uLrA9TneNEoa7RxnatzjcDSCmG1MXxSR1GAsXEV/Dwwykc2MPK8M2HN" 
  crossorigin="anonymous">
  <title>Disc Golfers Can't Read - Home</title>
  <style>section{ padding: 30px 0; }</style>
</head>
<body>
  <!-- heading tags -->
  

  <!-- navbar -->
  
  <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-md navbar-light">
    <div class="container-xxl">
      <a href="#intro" class="navbar-brand">
        <span class="fw-bold text-secondary">
          DGCR
        </span>
      </a>
      <!-- toggle button -->
      <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-bs-toggle="collapse" 
      data-bs-target="#main-nav" aria-controls="main-nav" aria-expanded="false" 
      aria-label="Toggle navigation">
        <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
      </button>
      
      <!-- navbar links -->
      <div class="collapse navbar-collapse justify-content-end align-center" 
      id="main-nav">
        <ul class="navbar-nav">
          <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link" href="background.html">Background</a>
          </li>
          <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link" href="equipment.html">Equipment</a>
          </li>
          <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link" href="rules.html">Rules</a>
          </li>
          <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link" href="how_to_play.html">How to Play</a>
          </li>
          <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link" href="links.html">Links</a>
          </li>
          <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link" href="contact.html">Contact Us</a>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </div>
  </nav>```
````

Answer (score 0):

Can you try?

```html
<button type="button" class="btn btn-lg btn-toggle" data-toggle="button" aria-pressed="false" autocomplete="off">
        <div class="handle"></div>
      </button>
```

Comment: I tried that code in place of my button code - it made the button invisible, but still wouldn't expand the links when clicked. I added  data-bs-target="#main-nav" as well to ensure I was still pointing to the correct  id.

Comment: https://codepen.io/aanjulena/pen/ZLZjzV look here please

Answer (score 0):

I've (sort of) worked out the solution. The issue was somewhere in my js script at the bottom of the body. There must have been an issue with where I had a return in order to make it multi-line - once I repasted it in single-line format, everything worked as intended. I carefully re-added breaks and it's still working. Cheers!

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).